Cannot make preselect value in select2 dropdown
I have select 2 dropdown in my project
Here is how it's added on view (Razor)
  <div class="form-group">
            <label class="required-label">Tier</label>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="PricingTierId" required>
                <option value="">@L("SelectAPricingTier")</option>
                @if (Model.PricingTierId.HasValue)
                {
                    <option selected value="@Model.PricingTierId">@Model.PricingTierName</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>

Then in js I initialize it like this
var _pricingTierDropdown = null;
_pricingTierDropdown = _$form.find('#PricingTierId');

            _pricingTierDropdown.select2Init({
                abpServiceMethod: abp.services.app.pricingTier.getPricingTiersSelectList,
                showAll: true,
                allowClear: true
            });

It's getting values from BE and everything is okay.
But I need to set preselected value in some cases
I tried to do it like this
  if(abp.features.isEnabled('App.PricingTiersFeature')){
            if (!_pricingTierDropdown.val()) {
                abp.services.app.pricingTier.getPricingTiersSelectList("", "").done(function (result) {
                    let def = result.items.filter(x => x.name === 'Retail');
                    console.log(def);
                    _pricingTierDropdown.val(def.id);
                    _pricingTierDropdown.trigger('change.select2');
                });
            }
        }

in console I got value for select like this, but it not appears as preselected

How I can fix this?

Could you try using below updated code to set preselected value:
if (abp.features.isEnabled('App.PricingTiersFeature')) {
    if (!_pricingTierDropdown.val()) {
        abp.services.app.pricingTier.getPricingTiersSelectList("", "").done(function (result) {
            let def = result.items.filter(x => x.name === 'Retail');
            console.log(def);

            // Check if def is not empty
            if (def.length > 0) {
                _pricingTierDropdown.val(def[0].id); // Set the value with the id of the first element
                _pricingTierDropdown.trigger('change.select2');
            }
        });
    }
}


It didn't help :(

@EugeneSukh did you got any error in console ?
